# Getting the position of each word in Tesseract

Tags: c#, position, tesseract, emgucv, drawrectangle

As shown below:
[Like this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHTua.png)

After extracting text from image (that i know), I want to get the position of each word in the Tesseract And then:
**First:** Draw a blue rectangle around each letter (exp: "t h e" or "q u i c k")
**Second:** Draw a red rectangle around each word (exp: "the" or "quick"
Also, how can I get the position of rows and columns word in the picture? I need it to add a 3D object to every word.
I use EmguCV in c#
Please help me how i do this.

Comment: Sounds like homework.

Comment: @Greg can you help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51282214/tesseract-ocr-text-position

Answer (score 0):

You've attached an image with `Tesseract OCR .NET Wrapper Demo` application.

This is an example of using `tessnet2` assembly. It's a wrapper over **Tesseract Engine**. A bit more information about this library is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041038/is-there-an-ocr-library-that-outputs-coordinates-of-words-found-within-an-image/41701492) and [here](http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/).

But you should understand that `tessnet 2` assembly is compatible with **Tesseract v 2.x** (and [datasets](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Data-Files)).

So you may need to work aroud if your're looking for the solution working with more comprehensive library versions which are supporting a list of langs.

Comment: thank you for responding. yes i use tesseract library and And my question is how can I draw a rectangle on words (like the picture).  I need an example. A pseudo code or anything in the C # language.  i use tesseract in emgucv

Comment: [Taking bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10902093/5195250) - this is the case. After retrieving bounding box of the word you can draw a rectangle based on min and max values.