# Createing Borders on a table in image in python

Tags: python, image, opencv

I have an image which have a table and some other data. I need to draw borders for table to separate out each cell.

My image looks like this [image]

What i am trying:
1) dilating the image to create continuous spots, which looks like [image]

2) finding contours and drawing

Issue: I am not able to draw correctly because it looks like my table cells are too close and while dilating they are becoming a continuous spot
**I took this code from Internet and was trying to modify But it did not work out well for this image

code :

```
    import os
    import cv2
    import imutils

    # This only works if there's only one table on a page
    # Important parameters:
    #  - morph_size
    #  - min_text_height_limit
    #  - max_text_height_limit
    #  - cell_threshold
    #  - min_columns


    def pre_process_image(img, save_in_file, morph_size=(7, 7)):
        # get rid of the color
        pre = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        # Otsu threshold
        pre = cv2.threshold(pre,250, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
        # dilate the text to make it solid spot
        cpy = pre.copy()
        struct = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, morph_size)
        cpy = cv2.dilate(~cpy, struct, anchor=(-1, -1), iterations=1)
        # cpy = cv2.dilate(img,kernel,iterations = 1)

        pre = ~cpy
        # pre=cpy
        if save_in_file is not None:
            cv2.imwrite(save_in_file, pre)
        return pre


    def find_text_boxes(pre, min_text_height_limit=3, max_text_height_limit=30):
        # Looking for the text spots contours
        contours = cv2.findContours(pre, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        # contours = contours[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else contours[1]
        contours = contours[0]
        # Getting the texts bounding boxes based on the text size assumptions
        boxes = []
        for contour in contours:
            box = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            h = box[3]

            if min_text_height_limit < h < max_text_height_limit:
                boxes.append(box)

        return boxes


    def find_table_in_boxes(boxes, cell_threshold=10, min_columns=2):
        rows = {}
        cols = {}

        # Clustering the bounding boxes by their positions
        for box in boxes:
            (x, y, w, h) = box
            col_key = x // cell_threshold
            row_key = y // cell_threshold
            cols[row_key] = [box] if col_key not in cols else cols[col_key] + [box]
            rows[row_key] = [box] if row_key not in rows else rows[row_key] + [box]

        # Filtering out the clusters having less than 2 cols
        table_cells = list(filter(lambda r: len(r) >= min_columns, rows.values()))
        # Sorting the row cells by x coord
        table_cells = [list(sorted(tb)) for tb in table_cells]
        # Sorting rows by the y coord
        table_cells = list(sorted(table_cells, key=lambda r: r[0][1]))

        return table_cells


    def build_lines(table_cells):
        if table_cells is None or len(table_cells) <= 0:
            return [], []

        max_last_col_width_row = max(table_cells, key=lambda b: b[-1][2])
        max_x = max_last_col_width_row[-1][0] + max_last_col_width_row[-1][2]

        max_last_row_height_box = max(table_cells[-1], key=lambda b: b[3])
        max_y = max_last_row_height_box[1] + max_last_row_height_box[3]

        hor_lines = []
        ver_lines = []

        for box in table_cells:
            x = box[0][0]
            y = box[0][1]
            hor_lines.append((x, y, max_x, y))

        for box in table_cells[0]:
            x = box[0]
            y = box[1]
            ver_lines.append((x, y, x, max_y))

        (x, y, w, h) = table_cells[0][-1]
        ver_lines.append((max_x, y, max_x, max_y))
        (x, y, w, h) = table_cells[0][0]
        hor_lines.append((x, max_y, max_x, max_y))

        return hor_lines, ver_lines

if __name__ == "__main__":
    in_file = os.path.join("data", "page1.jpg")
    pre_file = os.path.join("data", "pre.png")
    out_file = os.path.join("data", "out.png")

    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(in_file))

    pre_processed = pre_process_image(img, pre_file)
    text_boxes = find_text_boxes(pre_processed)
    cells = find_table_in_boxes(text_boxes)
    hor_lines, ver_lines = build_lines(cells)

    # Visualize the result
    vis = img.copy()

    # for box in text_boxes:
    #     (x, y, w, h) = box
    #     cv2.rectangle(vis, (x, y), (x + w - 2, y + h - 2), (0, 255, 0), 1)

    for line in hor_lines:
        [x1, y1, x2, y2] = line
        cv2.line(vis, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 1)

    for line in ver_lines:
        [x1, y1, x2, y2] = line
        cv2.line(vis, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 1)

    cv2.imwrite(out_file, vis)
```

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution for it? I'm facing a similar problem with no solutions :(

Comment: its been a long time. But i did it differently. First i extracted the (x,y) coordinates of all the char and than used simple geometry to find lines,cells,columns etc.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting application.

Raw dialating may not be the best way to do it.

I do recommend using OCR routing. Like below

[image]

The output is sthing like this

[image]

So as long as there is two row which are closer to each other. eg, row1-row2< npixel. then it is close line. the find the center position between (row1+height1)  and row2. The line should be pretty accurate.

in my sample if |292-335| < 50. then draw a line between (292+27 + 335) /2
means it's between asset line and the property line.

For the OCR package, you can try with tesseract if you insist with python.

```
https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/
```

See here for python text coordinate [Tesseract OCR Text Position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51282214/tesseract-ocr-text-position)

```
Tesseract.PageIteratorLevel myLevel = /*TODO*/;
using (var page = Engine.Process(img))
using (var iter = page.GetIterator())
{
    iter.Begin();
    do
    {
        if (iter.TryGetBoundingBox(myLevel, out var rect))
        {
            var curText = iter.GetText(myLevel);
            // Your code here, 'rect' should containt the location of the text, 'curText' contains the actual text itself
        }
    } while (iter.Next(myLevel));
}
```

**rect** contains the part you wanted  x y height width

The demo I show it here is actually using sth similar to windows OCR sample

```
https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/OCR
```

Feel free to try any of the methods to get the table line you wanted.

Comment: @Yuan Thanks It look Great. I will give it a try and will get back.

Comment: @yuan, Is there any source code to achieve this in Python

Comment: you can try this https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/10/using-tesseract-ocr-python/ . Then after that add the decision sample I made in the middle.

Comment: yeah, but would it give me the coordinates also for the text?

Comment: follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51282214/tesseract-ocr-text-position  it give yous location of the text. I update it in my post