# Python & OpenCV: How to add lines to gridless table

Tags: python, computer-vision, ocr, opencv

I have the following table:

[image]

I want to write a script that creates lines based on the natural breakages on the table text. The result would look like this:

[image]

Is there an OpenCV implementation that makes drawing these lines possible? I looked at the answers to the questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63287053/fill-missing-gap-in-table-structure-using-cv2-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56513713/createing-borders-on-a-table-in-image-in-python), but neither worked. What is the best approach to solving this problem?

Comment: Convert to grayscale and threshold so everything that is white stays white and all else becomes black. Then count the number of non-zero pixels (np.count_nonzero) in each row. Your lines would be drawn in the middle of each group of fully white rows.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you! Was having a brain block for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to get the horizontal lines in Python/OpenCV by counting the number of white pixels in each row of the image to find their center y values. The vertical lines can be added by a similar process.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread("table.png")
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# convert to grayscale 
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold gray image
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 254, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# count number of non-zero pixels in each row
count = np.count_nonzero(thresh, axis=1)

# threshold count at ww (width of image)
count_thresh = count.copy()
count_thresh[count==ww] = 255
count_thresh[count<ww] = 0
count_thresh = count_thresh.astype(np.uint8)

# get contours
contours = cv2.findContours(count_thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]

# loop over contours and get bounding boxes and ycenter and draw horizontal line at ycenter
result = img.copy()
for cntr in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)
    ycenter = y+h//2
    cv2.line(result, (0,ycenter), (ww-1,ycenter), (0, 0, 0), 2)

# write results
cv2.imwrite("table_thresh.png", thresh)
cv2.imwrite("table_lines.png", result)

# display results
cv2.imshow("THRESHOLD", thresh)
cv2.imshow("RESULT", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Threshold Image:

[image]

Result with lines:

[image]

**ADDITION**

Here is an alternate method that is slightly simpler. It averages the image down to one column rather than counting white pixels.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread("table.png")
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# convert to grayscale 
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# average gray image to one column
column = cv2.resize(gray, (1,hh), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

# threshold on white
thresh = cv2.threshold(column, 254, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# get contours
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]

# loop over contours and get bounding boxes and ycenter and draw horizontal line at ycenter
result = img.copy()
for cntr in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)
    ycenter = y+h//2
    cv2.line(result, (0,ycenter), (ww-1,ycenter), (0, 0, 0), 2)

# write results
cv2.imwrite("table_lines2.png", result)

# display results
cv2.imshow("RESULT", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: very helpful - more elegant than what I was able to come up with

Comment: Update: I ran the code and it works beautifully. Thanks again for the thoughtful answer!

Comment: See my addition in my answer for a slightly simpler method.

Comment: the simpler method works well. If it wouldn't be too much of a hassle, I was wondering how you'd implement vertical lines using the simpler method. I tried changing `column = cv2.resize(gray, (1, hh), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
thresh = cv2.threshold(column, 254, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]` to `row = cv2.resize(gray, (1, ww), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
thresh = cv2.threshold(row, 254, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]` but, when calling `cv2.drawContours`, see the contours still being drawn row-wise. Am I missing something? This is my first day using OpenCV

Comment: almost got it working using the first version. am just having trouble with the centering value. I currently have `xcenter = y+h//2`, which results in lines that are slightly off. (I used another image since the solid header interfered with column identification.)

Comment: center = x+w//2 if you are doing the vertical lines

Comment: This is very helpful, I use the code for my own work. It drew the horizontal ones successfully, but fail o generate the vertical ones? Can you have a look at it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68523822/draw-line-on-a-gridless-image-python-opencv

Comment: Can you add an explanation to your code? I've tried it for my own table image but it didn't draw anything :(

Comment: I created a question about it @fmw42 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75444109/draw-grid-on-a-gridless-fully-or-partially-table-image

Comment: Your image does not have any rows with pure white due to the vertical lines. So you need to adjust things like the threshold (lower it) or use a different method.