# Fill missing inner borders in a table in image with Python and OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, amazon-textract

I have a image containing multiple tables, some tables have missing inner horizontal borders which is causing merged cells with AWS Textract

This is the original image [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXQqt.png)
I tried this approach from [https://stackoverflow.com/a/67141649](https://stackoverflow.com):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread("table.png")
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# convert to grayscale 
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# average gray image to one column
column = cv2.resize(gray, (1,hh), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

# threshold on white
thresh = cv2.threshold(column, 254, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# get contours
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]

# loop over contours and get bounding boxes and ycenter and draw horizontal line at ycenter
result = img.copy()
for cntr in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)
    ycenter = y+h//2
    cv2.line(result, (0,ycenter), (ww-1,ycenter), (0, 0, 0), 2)

# write results
cv2.imwrite("table_lines2.png", result)

# display results
cv2.imshow("RESULT", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

and this is the result that i got:
[result after this approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqM79.png)

this is the expected result:
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Muy8.png)

I'm new to opencv and appreciate any help