# How to segment scanned pages into blocks of text

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I have lots of scanned pages that look like this:

[4 column example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vbOc.jpg)

[3 column example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vqvjg.jpg)

[4 column example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMtA6.jpg)

[2 column example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXcFQ.jpg)

I want to OCR them, but no matter what OEM or PSM I chose in Tesseract, they all get columns and lines wrong. So I decided it would probably be best to segment the images first into columns that I can then OCR, but this is way easier said than done.

For some, ie. 2 column examples, this code works well enough:

```
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("must have at least one file as parameter")
    sys.exit(1)

def process(img):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_canny = cv2.Canny(img_gray, 0, 0)
    return cv2.dilate(img_canny, np.ones((5, 5)), iterations=20)

def segment_file(old_fn, img):
    contours, hierarchies = cv2.findContours(process(img), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    i = 0
    for cnt in contours:
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        print("w * h = " + str(w * h))
        if w * h > 10000:
            new_fn = old_fn + "_" + str(i) + ".png"
            if not os.path.exists(new_fn):
                crop_img = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
                segmented_folder = "segmented/";
                os.makedirs(segmented_folder, exist_ok=True)
                cv2.imwrite(segmented_folder + new_fn, crop_img)
            i = i + 1

for i in range(1, len(sys.argv)):
    fn = sys.argv[i]

    if not os.path.exists(fn):
        print("{} does not exist" % fn)
        sys.exit(2)

    image = cv2.imread(fn)
    segment_file(fn, image)
```

`

But for other, it fails miserably, and sees the whole page as a single segment.

Is there any way to find blocks of text using OpenCV that will work on all of these types of images?

I don't have much experience regarding image segmentation, and googling only brought me settings from Tesseract (like PSM), of which I tried all and none worked for all kinds of documents. Tesseract, for lots of documents, merges 2 (or more) columns into a single line, ie. things like

```
this is column 1      this is column 2
and it has some       and it has some
text in it            other text in it
```

gets read as

```
this is column 1 this is column 2
and it has some and it has some
text in it other text in it
```

by Tesseract.

I have tens of thousands of these pages, so doing it manually is not an option.

Beneath the script posted earlier, I tried this:

```
IFS=$'\n'

for psm in $(seq 0 13); do
        for oem in $(seq 1 3); do
                for i in $(ls *.pdf); do
                        final_filename=$i.oem_${oem}_psm_${psm}.pdf
                        if [[ ! -e $final_filename ]]; then
                                docker run \
                                        --rm \
                                        -i jbarlow83/ocrmypdf \
                                        -j 2 \
                                        --language deu \
                                        --clean \
                                        --deskew \
                                        --rotate-pages \
                                        --rotate-pages-threshold 0.05 \
                                        --tesseract-pagesegmode $psm \
                                        --tesseract-oem $oem \
                                        - - <$i >$final_filename
                        fi
                        if [[ ! -s $final_filename ]]; then
                                echo "$final_filename is empty. Removing it."
                                rm "$final_filename"
                        fi
                done
        done
done
```

to try out every PSM and OEM setting for tesseract. But they all fail and read the lines/columns wrongly.

Comment: Average your image down to one row. Then find the segments of nearly pure white.  See for example how this was done for segmenting the opposite to put horizontal lines in a table by averaging to one column at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77619910/add-lines-if-a-table-is-borderless-using-opencv-in-python/77622063#77622063

Comment: `tesseract GMtA6.jpg - -l deu >out.txt` works very good on the command line.