# Find coordinates of text in image

Tags: node.js, adb, ocr

I am trying to develop an android automation project. So i wanted to get position of some text in android phone screen.

[My phone screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuwRm.png).
I trying to get position of the search box dynamically to click on the box using adb shell. Can i find the coordinates of the text "Search or type web address"? How can i do it?

I already tried tesseract.js . That is returning the extracted text only

*sorry for bad English*

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51282214/tesseract-ocr-text-position

Comment: You don't need image recognition for those cases. Try [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) and you can click by text or other attributes.